# Building a NSURL from a NSString and NSUserDefaults broken since Xcode 5 & Mavericks

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, xcode5, nsurl, osx-mavericks

We use a Mac App in our company that used to work perfectly in OS X Mountain Lion. After upgrading to OS X Mavericks it stopped working. Since we didn't upgrade all yet, we can clearly see that on ML machines it still works, where on Mavericks machines it doesn't.

Diving into the code and running it from Xcode 5 it quickly became clear that the following chunk of code that is responsible for building an API call to Trello is not behaving as expected:

```
NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:TRELLOTOKEN];    

NSLog(@"TOKEN: %@", token);    

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/1/cards/%@/idList?value=%@&key=%@&token=%@", taskID, DOINGLISTID, TRELLOKEY, token];    

NSLog(@"URLSTRING: %@", urlString); 

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TRELLOLOGENDPOINT]];  

NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
```

Output:

```
TOKEN: thetokenstring
URLSTRING: /1/cards/.../idList?value=...&key=...&token=thetokenstring
URL: (null)
```

I changed the taskID, DOINGLISTID, TRELLOKEY variables for ... to keep it short and anonymous.
I can assure the keys don't contain chars that need escaping (they would have needed escaping in ML too).

The problem is that my url variable remains null after assigning with the NSURL URLWithString function.

There is a way to fix this situation by just assigning a string to the NSString *token variable. So if we replace the first line with:

```
NSString *token = @"thetokenstring";
```

Then it works. You can simply copy paste the token from the NSLog output if you like.

Output:

```
TOKEN: thetokenstring
URLSTRING: /1/cards/.../idList?value=...&key=...&token=thetokenstring
URL: /1/cards/.../idList?value=...&key=...&token=thetokenstring -- https://trello.com
```

Obviously I need my token from my NSUserDefaults.

Could anybody shine a light on this? I would like to know why this doesn't work (any more) and how I might be able to fix it.

I already tried the following:

- Explicitly casting the NSUserDefaults result to a NSString.
- Initializing the NSString *token with:

  [NSString stringWithString:...]

Unfortunately no luck...

Comment: This is a bit of a weird suggestion but try `NSLog(@"%@", [NSArray arrayWithObject:token]);`. Array descriptions use old-style ASCII plist format and that will highlight if `token` contains something you don't expect. I guess I'd also log `[token class]` while I'm at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Based on Ken Thomases' excellent comment.

It turned out that the token contained a newline char. Sounds pretty stupid eh? This could happen because I have to filter the code out of the DOM of a very simple page after the user authorises the app.

I suppose the implementation of NSURL changed a bit so it doesn't allow for a newline char at the end of the url string (and it shouldn't). I wouldn't exclude the existence of any other feasible explanations though.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the implementation of `NSURL` has changed in this way. There is mention in the release notes of how it wasn't properly checking single character strings before, but nothing beyond that

Comment: Well it seems I have no choice but to be very surprised. My testing suggests that prior to 10.9, `+URLWithString:` and friends will cheerfully allow the *last* character to be anything at all, percent encoding it if needed. Invalid characters in **any** other position will cause `nil` to be returned. I suspect the release note simply isn't broad enough

Answer (score -1):

the code seems to be ok!
anyway, you could replace the first line with this one to see if it works or not:

```
NSString *token = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:TRELLOTOKEN] description];
```

this is just a thought and it may be the case or not! my thought is the method you used is returning `(id)`, which is OK to pass it to `NSString`, it should work as it is working in the output of `NSLog` message (and the previous operating systems). the description method just returns `(NSString *)` which is the same kind of the token object. `(id)` is dynamic typing and may cause some problems. It's good to write code the way you tell that you want exactly to return `NSString`!
by the way, `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:TRELLOTOKEN]` may return `nil` (depending on the logic of your code!). so it's best practice to use it like this:

```
NSString *token;
NSObject *tokenObj = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:TRELLOTOKEN];
if (token != nil) {
    token = [tokenObj description];
} else {
    token = @"";
}
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/1/cards/%@/idList?value=%@&key=%@&token=%@", taskID, DOINGLISTID, TRELLOKEY, token];    
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TRELLOLOGENDPOINT]];
NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
```

hope to solve your dilemma! ;)

Comment: Why replace the first line with that? Please give a reason don't just say do this and not explain why -1 based on that I will remove if improved.

Comment: the method you used is returning (id), which is OK to pass it to NSString, it should work as it is working in the output NSLog message (and the previous operating systems). the description method just returns (NSString *) which is the same kind of the token object. (id) is dynamic typing and my cause some problem. It's just a simple thought! the conclusion i made may not be the case here!

Comment: Please update your answer with that. What if something is returned that doesn't have the method `description`? What would happen if `nil` is returned as `nil` doesn't have `description` the code will crash at this line.

Comment: any object in Objectiv-C world has description method. btw, you can override the description method to return an NSString that is suitable for you.
when you (in your code) assign the output to an NSString object (token), you are actually putting what the description method returns. but here you say I want the output type to be specifically NSString not (id)!
can you at least try that and give a feedback that the problem solves or still remains the same?

Comment: It's not me who has the issue. I'm questioning your code because if `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:TRELLOTOKEN]` returns `nil` then this line will crash. `nil` is not an object so `nil` it would mean nothing has been assigned to that object so when you run `description` on nil it's like doing `[nil description];` and this will just break the world. So whilst this may seem to work at first it isn't correct because of that reason so your code is wrong and will create more bugs then fixing.

Comment: Ahhh! got your point!
yes, you are right, the output could be nil.
so you could get the output as an (id) object, the see if it's nil or not. then call the description method!
btw, I didn't say anywhere that your code is wrong and mine is right and you should use it this way! do it as you like!

Comment: btw! you can call any method you like on the nil object!
it won't just do anything!
`NSObject * theNullObject = nil; [theNullObject description];`

Comment: You don't seem to be reading my comments. I'm not the person asking the question (The one with the issue) I am a random developer questioning your answer to improve it. Just saying use this is not a good answer you need to edit your answer to explain yourself. I honestly don't care whether this returns `nil` or not I am trying to get you to improve the actual answer not comment about it.

Comment: :D I'm sorry about that. I thought I was having fight with the questioner! :D I'll do that. Thanks. :)

Comment: Apart from the nil-discussion, I just tried to use the explicit description. Unfortunately this doesn't help. Same result.

Comment: As promised the answer has been improved so I have removed my -1